# Subject call to next causing a strange error

Tags: javascript, rxjs

This causes the following error: `Cannot read property 'length' of undefined`

```
const msg$ = new Subject<string>();
msg$.subscribe(console.log)
of("Hello").subscribe(msg$.next);
```

---

If, however, I wrap msg$.next in a function, then it works without any errors.

- Lambda function

```
const msg$ = new Subject<string>();
msg$.subscribe(console.log)
of("Hello").subscribe(greeting => msg$.next(greeting));
```

- Anonymous function

```
const msg$ = new Subject<string>();
msg$.subscribe(console.log)
of("Hello").subscribe(function(greeting){
  msg$.next(greeting);
});
```

- Named function

```
function nextMsg(greeting){
  msg$.next(greeting);
}
const msg$ = new Subject<string>();
msg$.subscribe(console.log)
of("Hello").subscribe(nextMsg);
```

---

They're all just wrapper functions that seemingly do nothing but call the next function. What's going on here? Seems like there's a JavaScript gotcha I'm not aware of at work here.

Comment: I think this question comes down to "What's the value of "this" when passing a function as parameter?". You might find some answers here [How to access the correct `this` inside a callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback). `this` has the wrong value in your fist example. If you put a `console.log(this)` inside `nextMsg` you will see that it's a `SafeSubscriber` which lacks the property `observers.length` that is accessed. The `Subject.next` function in rxjs6 relies on `this` to be a `Subject` with a `observers.length` property.

Comment: Yup, of course. Seems silly that I didn't notice. `msg$.next.bind(msg$)` works. `a.func` doesn't have `a` as a context, whereas `a.func()` does. If you put your comment as an answer, I'd accept that.

Comment: It will also work if you would use `source$.subscribe(subjectInstance)`. It will automatically call `subject.{next,error,complete}()`, depending on what `source$` emits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Accepted answer for posterity's sake

---

> I think this question comes down to "What's the value of "this" when passing a function as parameter?". You might find some answers here [How to access the correct this inside a callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback).
>
> `this` has the wrong value in your first example. If you put a `console.log(this)` inside `nextMsg` you will see that it's a `SafeSubscriber` which lacks the property `observers.length` that is accessed. The `Subject#next` function in rxjs6 relies on this to be a `Subject` with an `observers.length` property

Yup, of course. Seems silly that I didn't notice. `msg$.next.bind(msg$)` works.

`obj.func` doesn't have `obj` as a context, whereas `obj.func()` does.